# How to get out of year long work agreement without penalty?

Tags: termination, relocation

Let me preface this by saying I am prepared to accept this may be impossible but it never hurts to ask so...here it goes.

Recently I decided to transfer to another location of the company I work for because I was unhappy with my previous geographic location. This move took me across the United States. My company offers a relocation package where they cover the cost of the entire move as long as you promise to stay with the company for at least 12 months. I cannot leave voluntarily or be fired "for cause." I was already not in love with the job but I thought the quality of my life would greatly improve if I lived somewhere that I greatly preferred to be.

I love where I live now *but* I am having major problems at work. I am feeling totally incompetent/unqualified and I have lost all interest in continuing my career. I was getting by at my previous location where I was working on a low priority legacy project but here it is the complete opposite. The required skillset is simply higher than I what I posses.

When I brought this feeling of inadequacy up to my manager, he began giving me more "simple" tasks but even those I am struggling to finish at a decent pace. I even mentioned switching to a different technical position but realized it wouldn't make a difference because I still don't have any interest in this line of work.

All of this has resulted in a constant feeling of anxiety and impending doom. Every moment of every day I feel anxious because I know that I am barely scraping by. Even when I am off of work, the only thing I can think about is the next day at work which terrifies me. I do not want to live the next 7-8 months of my life like this but I signed a contract and having to pay for a cross country relocation will be a massive financial blow.

I understand that all of this is my doing and I am paying the price for the decisions I've made. That said, what are, if any exist, my options besides repayment?

**Edit**: It's probably too late to include this detail but I have no desire to continue working in this line of work, for any company. I have poor stress management abilities and the anxiety is debilitating both at and outside of work.

Comment: What would be your future plans **if** you get out? Do you have a good chance of landing a good job elsewhere?

Comment: Your options are either continue working there, or repay the relocation costs. The only way I can think of to offset that would be to find another job willing to pay you a signing bonus, which you can put towards paying back your current employer.

Comment: How much are we talking about here? $20,000? $30,000? Your employer would be foolish to try to collect it all at once. Also, if you start paying it down every month, your employer would be foolish to ruin your professional reputation over that since you wouldn't be able to pay that money back if you no longer were able to get high paying jobs.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk the feel of comments and few of the answers is that taking a reloc bonus from a company is akin to signing your life away for X time unless you can repay the money ad-hoc. And if you don't they will ruin your career, shoot your dog and hound your every step, sparing no expense to ruin your life if you won't pay right away. And that's just silly, and any company doing so would be wasting money, also opening itself to myriad of lawsuits.

Comment: @Daniel I have decided the corporate life isn't for me and have no desire to land a good job elsewhere. Truthfully, I have been motivated by all of this to finally start my own business. I've begun setting things up and it's already showing early signs of promise. Nothing is guaranteed but I feel excited about my life for the first time since I can remember and know it will bring me satisfaction in the long run.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I haven't estimated it, too afraid to know what the number is but I suspect it would be in the $20,000 to $30,000 range.

Comment: @SoraPro In that case I suggest to soldier through and use the time to prepare your business in your free time. I´ve been both freelance and part of a startup. You´ll need all the money you can get in the beginning - and $20-30k is a big hole in the budget. Also a lot of the prep work can really weigh you down once business starts running. So get all the legal, branding, ... etc. out of the way. 8 month is so not long for this!

Comment: Welcome to indentured servitude.

Comment: @SoraPro Where are these "feelings" coming from?  Are you getting poor performance review week by week or are you doing self-evaluation and somehow concluded that you're inadequate? What about your previous location? Sometimes we're our worst critic and you gotta know where it is coming from.

Comment: @Nelson It is mostly the product of self-evaluation but it is obvious how I compare to others. We have daily meetings and my teammates are able to explain in deep detail what they are working on because they have a low level understanding of it all. I am simply not on that level and have struggled for nearly 2 years now to get there. It isn't clicking for me. I understand we can be our own worst critic but I know where I stand here.

Answer (score 9):

There are no other options here.  Either you work the additional time or you repay the relo.

Or you can try to talk them into another deal (forgiveness, pro rating) but that discussion is hard to have as it starts with "Well, so I want to leave even though I said I was going to stay and in good faith you paid to move me across the country." They don't really have any incentive to change it other than to "be nice to you," which might work if it's your boss's call but not if there's other teams, HR, legal involved.

A lot of people work jobs that aren’t their passion to put food on the table, so in general I’d counsel you to “get a grip.”  Learn, work, do better.  Your anxiety may be getting to a point where if you are unable to master yourself you should seek some professional therapist help.

Just leaving and refusing to pay may or may not result in them taking legal action to get the money back, but at a minimum it burns a reference hard. If I heard “he skipped out on his relo repayment” about a prospective employee, they'd be as hireable as Kryptonite. Or if I heard them say the sentence “There is always an option to get out of your obligations.” Both speak to poor character that would make it hard for me to engage in agreements of trust with them.

Comment: There is always an option to get out of your obligations, just got to go and talk to people and find out what the alternative is. Stating with no uncertainty that this doesn't exist is just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This was going to be a comment, but I think it extends to an answer - however it is not the answer to your question.

---

I'd argue that you are in a great position(*).  You love where you live now and you can't be fired for cause, and your manager is willing to work with you.  So you actually have nothing you should be worrying about with your job itself.

However you may be suffering from some form of Imposter Syndrome such as mentioned [in this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/143423/50253) which may be being exacerbated by feeling trapped by the contract you signed.

My advice is that you should try to stick out that remaining 8 months - but to do so successfully you need to get back that personal spark that brought you to your company in the first place.  That means working on yourself and what makes you you and working on methods that allow you control your anxiety and fears.  That may also mean getting professional advice, but I am not qualified to to advise on that.   Or it may mean taking a vacation and getting totally away from work for a bit.

I would also verify the terms of your contract with a fine toothed comb and look for any and every possible "out".  Because even just the knowledge that you have a potential escape can alleviate some of the stress you are feeling.

---

*In saying so I am not trying to trivialize what you are feeling.  You obviously are going through a very stressful period in your life right now.

Comment: I don’t think OP meant they can not be fired for cause, but rather if they are they have to reimburse the relocation.

Comment: This is correct @AsheraH

Comment: @SoraPro This language is ambiguous and caused my confusion *I cannot leave voluntarily or be fired "for cause."*.

Answer (score -1):

From my experience, it is required to spend between 3-6 months before feeling comfortable after starting a new position.
Also from my own experience, the harder I work at the beginning, the shorter this period turns.

I agree with spending some away, may be traveling, to tidy your mind.

Answer (score -3):

You have a very simple alternative to repayment - talking to your boss. While going strictly by the paperwork you owe the money, it's almost always not worth chasing for it, more so if you will refuse to pay on your own, and instead they will have to go after you to collect. That is expensive, and together with your seemingly okay relation with your boss, use this together to see what can you agree on.

There are many options, you can agree to pro-rate the fee by months left in the contract, or agree to the acceptable repayment plan, or even agree to just part ways with no money changing hands. More so if you will explain what you've explained to us - the crushing feeling you have, unable to relax and that you are leaving because of how the work impacts your mental health. 
Or maybe they will have another solution to help you grow into the role, without as much stress, who knows.

Worst case is that you may hear outright "no", but in my experience, that is unlikely if you are honest about the situation.

Comment: No, worst case scenario is that they make moves to terminate for cause, and then recover the money,

Comment: @RichardSaysReinstateMonica OP already wants to quit, how is that going to be worse? In most states of USA getting fired is better, as then you may be eligible for unemployment at least.

Comment: “When you are terminated for cause or misconduct, you may not be eligible for unemployment benefits. ... In some states, being fired for misconduct bars you from receiving unemployment benefits permanently; in others, it only prevents you from receiving compensation for a limited period.“

Comment: Plus, it burns a reference hard.  If I heard “he skipped out on his relo repayment” he’d be as hireable as Kryptonite.  Or if I heard him say the sentence “ There is always an option to get out of your obligations.”

Comment: @mxyzplksaysreinstateMonica Right, in some states, we don't know a state so we cannot assume the law. Also if they don't have enough for the cause now, speaking about wanting to quit due to mental health issues is not giving one. Actually makes it less likely, as now you've fired an employee after he raised mental health concerns caused by the workplace. More and more reasons to cut a deal instead.

Comment: @mxyzplksaysreinstateMonica And the "skipped out of relo repayment" is very much nonsense. This is not a detail anyone would ever pass when a potential employee calls for a reference. Not until you have a court judgment to collect the reloc money at least, as until then the money is not skipped on. And going to cour to pursue the money is expensive, and even then it's debatable whether you have the right to pass this information to anyone outside.

Comment: @mxyzplksaysreinstateMonica Also, as i had to brush up on over-the-pond law, to fire someone with "poor performance" as the cause, would require documented performance issues, and lack of improvement over a period of time. It's not as easy as saying "you don't perform, we can now fire you with cause", it's actually very rare to go this way, as it's too much of a gray line to take, opening you to a costly lawsuit/hearing. In that case, it's much better to agree to part ways, for both sides, and what usully happens.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul The law, and the application of the law are two things.  You can fire someone for having their socks untied, if it's in the employee code of conduct.  Sorry, I've seen it happen too many times.  Skipped out on relo repayment will burn you in the industry for YEARS.  American companies like to play rough, and they will **ABSOLUTELY** go after relo expenses just on principle.

Comment: @RichardSaysReinstateMonica I don't suggest "skipping" (which is a term for going AWOL on payments), did nowhere in my answer or comments. Just that OP goes and talks with his boss at the company and see if they can cut any type of a deal. Because if they agree to some alternative, like repaying only half, and OP repays it then the matter is closed. If then the company were to try to say "oh he only repaid part of his relocation fee" would be a lie and would make them vulnerable to a civil suit by OP, as their claim is already satisfied and they agreed to it (even if that may sound a bit odd).

Comment: @RichardSaysReinstateMonica I think the confusion came because I explained how expensive it is to collect money (against a person with no assets, unsecured claim, we are looking at 40%+ cost to collect). This is not me suggesting for op to skip, but that company will absolutely use this to calculate whether it's worth to give OP a break, as the possible alternative is expensive.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Relo expenses are one of the few things that American companies will go after on principle because they know if they don't, they will have people doing it all the time.  They will even recover at a loss to make an example of the person who did it, AND they will make sure it's known in the industy.  It's one of those things you don't want to mess with.

Comment: @RichardSaysReinstateMonica I seriously doubt that they will try to pound blood out of a stone, and I think you are exaggerating unless there is some citation to back it up. It's a nice idea for propaganda's sake, but a hardly sustainable business model to do so. 

When someone owes you money, say 10k for relocation, they cannot repay it, but will offer you at least 50% instead, right now then it's prudent to take the 50% and be happy.  Refusing a sensible repayment offer may also weaken your claim, but that's a bit too nuanced for comments.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I'm smart enough not to name names.  But I will say a major telecom was known for this one.

Comment: @RichardSaysReinstateMonica So you are basing view of all american businesses based on one major telecom company, without even an article to back it up? That's gossip then.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul no, just giving a single example, but go ahead, believe what you wish.  You know better than someone with decades in the American work force.

Comment: @RichardSaysReinstateMonica You are confusing knowledge with belief. Knowledge comes with sources, like a study of how many US companies decided to pursue a relocation fee and refused to accept even the smallest reduction in exchange for prompt payment, deciding to take a loss instead. Belief is "because I heard anegdotes I believe that companies do it".

Comment: @RichardSaysReinstateMonica, Also, there is no point in ruining someone's professional reputation if that person starts paying you $100-150 a month. If you ruin that person's professional reputation and make it difficult for them to get another high paying job, then you might as well kiss that monthly payment goodbye.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk yep, never happens.